# Kong with OWASP ModSecurity optional configuration include

Tags: nginx, kong, mod-security

For customizing of ModSecurity configuration I have included to the **modsecurity.conf** following line:

> Include /etc/modsecurity/*.conf

But without any conf file in the directory (usual case on my enviroment), a kong failing during startup

> Error: could not prepare Kong prefix at /usr/local/kong: nginx
> configuration is invalid (exit code 1): nginx: [emerg]
> "modsecurity_rules_file" directive Rules error. File:
> /usr/local/kong/modsecurity.conf. Line: 268. Column: 31.
> /etc/modsecurity/*.conf: Not able to open file. Looking at:
> '/etc/modsecurity/*.conf', '/etc/modsecurity/*.conf',
> '/usr/local/kong//etc/modsecurity/*.conf',
> '/usr/local/kong//etc/modsecurity/*.conf'. in
> /usr/local/kong/nginx-kong.conf:69 nginx: configuration file
> /usr/local/kong/nginx.conf test failed

**IncludeOptional** not supported by kong.

How I can solve the case with optional include?

Kong version 1.2.X

Comment: I do not know Kong, but I think this is not a Kong issue, rather than libmodsecurity3 - which version do you have? As I remember the earlier versions didn't support the meta characters, like `*`.

Comment: @airween , I don't think * not supported. If any file present in the folder, everything works well, but fails on empty folder.

Comment: Ah, I see - sorry. I did not realized you also wrote the empty directory issue. The absence of 'IncludeOptional' keyword is a big problem... You can put an empty file with name 'empty.conf' - this can be help.

Comment: @airween , as a hotfix I have already put an empty file. it works. Thx for attention!